# Writing a VBA macro that evaluates an IF statement in a specified cell range in SheetA that sets the text color of two cell ranges in SheetB

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

I have gotten this to run but it is not working properly.  (Interestingly, only one cell in my specified SheetB is being changed to the red font upon running.) My assumption is that I am not specifying which sheets and/or ranges to use at the proper locations in the script, or that my syntax is plainly just wrong. Thank you for your help.

```
Sub RedBold()
'Sets color of current cell to red  
With ActiveCell.Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True 
End Sub

Option Explicit

Sub LowInventory()

Dim cell As Range
Dim deltaQ As Range

'Assign specific cell range in the Inventory Quantities sheet to variable          deltaQ
Set deltaQ = Sheets("Inventory Quantities").[E3:E190]

'Conditional loop that checks for low deltaQ values and assigns a color to   two specific cell ranges in the Inventory Costs, Sources sheet
For Each cell In deltaQ.Cells
    'if deltaQ value is less than 2
    If cell.Value < 2 Then
        'Specify cell ranges in specific sheet to be affected by low inventory check loop
        Sheets("Inventory Costs, Sources").Range("B3:B190, C3:C190").Select
        Call RedBold
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `ActiveCell` in your `RedBold` sub is the only cell being affected, you want the `Range` to be affected; you could do this in quite a few different ways, e.g. passing as a parameter to the `RedBold` function, or acting on the `Range` directly (`Sheets("Inventory Costs, Sources").Range("B3:B190, C3:C190").Font = ...`) ..

Comment: My intention is to have the macro check each cell within the range specified of the "...Quantities" sheet, and to color the corresponding cells within the ranges specified of the "Inventory..." sheet if the specified condition is met.  I implemented your suggestion within the "RedBold" sub macro, but that isn't the result I am looking for.